# How to compile a program (with gcc)?

Tags: java, gcc

I am writing a cross-platform IDE, and am wondering what the best way to compile a program (with gcc) using java code.  (It's also a cross-language IDE)

Should I access the command prompt/terminal?

Also can I have some example code?

Comment: There is no Java API for calling gcc.  You need to invoke it like any other executable program, of which there is plenty of examples readily available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just execute `gcc` in a separate process.  But rather than handling this all yourself, use something like [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/), which is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: Can I have some example code?

Comment: @Tyranitar: Not off the top of my head.  Take a look at the documentation at the link I posted (in particular the Tutorial page)...